# Limit BitTorrent client onboard QNAP TS-210 to download only

Tags: nas, file-sharing, bittorrent, upload

I have a QNAP TS-210 NAS device with Linux version of BitTorrent client embed into their native system. For legal reasons in my country, I'd like to become a "*100% certified leech*" and limit my client's upload to zero<sup>1</sup>. Is there anyway I can do this?

So far, I've found out, that I can't use settings like `Global maximum upload rate` or `Maximum upload rate per torrent` to `0`, because `0` means *unlimited* in case of my BitTorrent client. I've tried to enter values like `0.001` kB/s (which isn't perfect, but still better  than nothing), but this value is rounded to `0`, which -- effectively -- means *unlimited* again.

I've set `Share Ratio` to `0%`, but it doesn't changed anything -- my client is still uploading (I don't know, if this is because bugs in it or if I'm changing wrong setting -- I'm total BitTorrent newbie / ignorant).

Any help is highly apperciated.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I'm perfectly aware, that I can be quickly banned on many torrent sites / servers for being leech / not sharing anything. You don't have to remind me that. But, I'm willing to take that risk, because legal situation in my country has become quite very bad these days.</sub>

Comment: Most of these clients are open source.  Modify the source so 0 means 0 kb/sec if you want.  You can also configure your network to only allow the incoming traffic but block the outgoing traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong stat.  You want to change the seeding ratio.  That determines how much to upload, not the upload speed.

As stated, you will most likely have issues downloading without uploading.  Most tracker sites will limit your speed greatly if you dont upload, or just ban you altogether.

Comment: So... setting `Global maximum upload rate` to 0 / very low value should do the trick, right? If `Share Ratio` is wrong. There are no settings related to speed, seed or share, other than I just mentioned, in my BitTorrent client.